# T-SQL, XQuery Invalid Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery-sql

I'm just learning XQUERY and trying to accomplish what I thought would be very simple. Here's my T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @XML xml
set @xml = '<resultsets><AppVersion>13.0</AppVersion></resultsets>'

-- Code below is wrong
select 
ResultSets.AppVersion.query('AppVersion').value('.', 'varchar(100)') as AppVersion
from @XML.nodes('/resultsets/AppVersion') ResultSets(AppVersion)
```

I cannot figure out exactly how to query that inner element, appversion. I'm not getting any errors, but I'm unable to return that 13.0 within the appversion inner-element. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You've got one `AppVersion` too many. This returns your `13.0` :

```
DECLARE @XML xml
set @xml = '<resultsets><AppVersion>13.0</AppVersion></resultsets>'

-- Code below is right
select 
ResultSets.AppVersion.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as AppVersion
from @XML.nodes('/resultsets/AppVersion') ResultSets(AppVersion)
```

Your `nodes` method already gets down to the `AppVersion` nodes, so from there you don't need a further `query`, just the `value`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one row as a result there is no need to use `nodes`.

```
DECLARE @XML xml
set @xml = '<resultsets><AppVersion>13.0</AppVersion></resultsets>'

select @XML.value('(/resultsets/AppVersion)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as AppVersion
```