# Parsing TFS 2010 Process Arguments XML with T-SQL and XQuery

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, namespaces, xquery

I am trying to the get the value of the x:String node **(L1.0.0.0)** in XML below shown code sample. The XML in the sample is generated by the TFS 2010 when we queue the builds. The XML has two major nodes and **Dictionary** and **x:String** and I have tried the query similar to the other stack overflow thread and I have included that under additional research. Any one got any suggestions why my XQuery is not working?

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
SET @XML = '<Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object" 
xmlns="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">   
<x:String x:Key="GetVersion">L1.0.0.0</x:String> 
</Dictionary>'


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib' AS a,
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS x)

SELECT @XML.value('(/Dictionary/x:String)[1]', varchar(100)) AS BuildLabel
```

Additional Research
Stack Overflow
[T-SQL, XQuery Invalid Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590183/t-sql-xquery-invalid-column)

[How to work with multiple namespaces](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10318/xquery-lab-37-working-with-multiple-namespaces.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query you need to prefix `Dictionary` with `a` since `clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib` is the default namespace and `Dictionary` belongs to that.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
'clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib' AS a,
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS x)
SELECT @XML.value('(/a:Dictionary/x:String)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS BuildLabel
```

Or you can specify the namespace as default in the query.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' as x,
                     DEFAULT 'clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib')
SELECT @XML.value('(/Dictionary/x:String)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS BuildLabel
```